# DropWizard non-trivial configuration validation

Tags: java, configuration, dropwizard, bean-validation, javax.validation

I have a DropWizard configuration class that has two properties.
At least one must be set.
That means, both are `@Nullable` and I need validation on the whole object.

```
    public class MessagingStreamConfiguration extends Configuration
    {
        @Nullable
        private URL baseUrl;

        @Nullable
        private LinkedHashMap<String, URL> baseUrls;
    }
```

This configuration class is a property of the whole application's configuration.

```
public class ClaConfiguration extends Configuration
{
    @Valid
    @JsonProperty("messagingStream")
    private MessagingStreamConfiguration messagingStreamConfiguration;
```

I set up a `javax.validation` for that:

```
/**
 * Additional validation for non-trivial cases.
 */
private boolean isValid() {
    return (this.getBaseUrl() == null
        && (this.getBaseUrls() == null || this.getBaseUrls().isEmpty()));
}


/**
 * javax.validation way of validating the whole class.
 */
public static class MessagingStreamConfigurationValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MessagingStreamConfigurationValid, MessagingStreamConfiguration>
{
    @Override
    public void initialize(MessagingStreamConfigurationValid constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MessagingStreamConfiguration conf, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return conf.isValid();
    }
}

@Constraint(validatedBy = {MessagingStreamConfigurationValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MessagingStreamConfigurationValid
{
    String message() default "Neither baseUrl nor baseUrls is set. Set baseUrls.";
}
```

But the validation of the object does not happen. Only of it's individual fields.

The [only relevant DropWizard tests I found](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-configuration/src/test/java/io/dropwizard/configuration/ConfigurationValidationExceptionTest.java), [2nd](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldConfiguration.java) also only deals with fields.
The DW documentation [doesn't talk about config validation](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.5/docs/manual/validation.html) much.

**How can I make DropWizard validate the whole object?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

- annotate the class to be validated (`ClaConfiguration`) with your custom annotation (`MessagingStreamConfigurationValid`)
- in your annotation, target `ElementType.FIELD`, and annotate your field with your custom annotation instead of `@Valid`

Please note that you need [two more attributes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-constraintannotation) in your annotation to get it to work:

- `Class<?>[] groups() default { };`
- `Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };`

Comment: Interesting, I thought the groups and payload were example-specific. Now I see they are actually needed. Will try.